# How can I execute an environment variable as code?

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I have the following Perl code that uses an environment variable `$X`:

```
printf("%s", substr($ENV{X}, 4));
```

Without changing the Perl code, what can I set `$X` to so that Perl exits with status 1 before the `printf` returns? I thought `${\(exit 1)}` would work but apparently I don't understand how Perl reads environment variables.

Comment: The only way to execute code in a string is with `eval()`.

Comment: String interpolation only happens when compiling source.  (`eval` counts as compiling source).  Already encoded strings don't need interpolation.  Fortunately Perl is not vulnerable to the "Shellshock" like vulnerability that you're looking for.

Comment: @tjd: No, string interpolation happens at run time.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can do. Executing data as Perl code when simply trying to fetch it? That would be bad.

`${\(exit 1)}` is an expression that calls `exit`. `$ENV{X}` is an expression that returns a string (the value of env var `X`).

You'd need to pass the contents of `$ENV{X}` to the Perl parser as Perl code. Passing Perl code to the parser can be from within Perl using the following:

- `eval EXPR` (including `s///ee`)
- `do PATH`
- `require PATH`
- `require Module`
- `use Module`
- `no Module`

From outside of `perl`, you can use

- `perl PATH`
- `perl <PATH`
- `perl -e EXPR`
- `perl -E EXPR`
- `perl -MModule`
- `perl -mModule`

Also, command line options can be passed via `PERL5OPT`.